# Stream analytics - Pocessing JSON with no array name

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, stream-analytics

I would like to convert this array to rows using a stream analytics query containing the CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements() but this function requires an array name. Obviously there is no name. Any suggestions?

Example of JSON to parse :

```
{
  "Alert1": {
    "Site": "11109370",
    "Sensor": "UPS",
    "Event": "Load Not Protected",
    "Time": "08-28-2019 10:39:02",
    "Value": "0",
    "Threshold": 0,
    "Severity": "2",
    "Status": "Open"
  },
  "Alert2": {
    "Site": "11109370",
    "Sensor": "UPS",
    "Event": "Emergency stop",
    "Time": "08-28-2019 10:39:02",
    "Value": "1",
    "Threshold": 1,
    "Severity": "2",
    "Status": "Open"
  },
  "Alert3": {
    "Site": "11109370",
    "Sensor": "UPS",
    "Event": "Load Protected(UPS Coupled)",
    "Time": "08-28-2019 10:39:02",
    "Value": "0",
    "Threshold": 0,
    "Severity": "1",
    "Status": "Open"
  },
  "Alert4": {
    "Site": "11109370",
    "Sensor": "UPS",
    "Event": "Battery Deep Discharge Protection",
    "Time": "08-28-2019 10:39:02",
    "Value": "0",
    "Threshold": 0,
    "Severity": "1",
    "Status": "Open"
  },
  "Alert5": {
    "Site": "11109370",
    "Sensor": "UPS",
    "Event": "Battery Present",
    "Time": "08-28-2019 10:39:02",
    "Value": "0",
    "Threshold": 0,
    "Severity": "1",
    "Status": "Open"
  },
  "Alert6": {
    "Site": "11109370",
    "Sensor": "UPS",
    "Event": "Sensor Communication Error",
    "Time": "08-28-2019 10:39:02",
    "Status": "Close"
  }
}
```

I tried the code below but I encountered an error :

**Error : Invalid column name: 'arrayvalue'. Column with such name does not exist.**

```
SELECT message.ArrayValue
FROM INPUT as event
CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(event) AS message
```

Comment: Your example data is not array,it's an object? Any desired output you could share with me?

Comment: How do you want to set the ·Alert1,Alert2...· key name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your direction is right,however, i think you made a little mistake about the usage of `GetRecordProperties` function.

Please see the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/getrecordproperties-azure-stream-analytics) stated in the official document,not any `ArrayValue` properties:

```
SELECT   
    recordProperty.PropertyName,  
    recordProperty.PropertyValue  
FROM input as event  
CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(event.recordField) AS recordProperty
```

For your situation, you could execute below sql:

```
SELECT   
    recordProperty.PropertyName,  
    recordProperty.PropertyValue  
FROM input as event  
CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(event) AS recordProperty
```

Output:

[image]

As i asked that how you want to deal with `Alert1,Alert2` properties,if you want to get rid of them,then use below sql:

```
SELECT    
    recordProperty.PropertyValue.Site,  recordProperty.PropertyValue.Sensor....<more your columns>
FROM input as event  
CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(event) AS recordProperty
```

Output:

[image]